# Codeigniter in subdomain issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter instance in a web server subdirectory, **www/CI**.
My **www/CI/application/config/config.php** file is configured with:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://CI.example.com/';
```

I also have a subdomain '**CI.example.com**' pointing to that CI directory. My **www/CI/.htaccess** file is just the standard in these cases for removing the 'index.php' string:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Every URL inside my CI app is working fine, except the root one: 'CI.example.com'. When I try to access this one, the directives in **www/.htaccess** (the upper, main domain) are applied and this results in an undesired behaviour...

Could you help with this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally came up to a solution:

I noticed that all the directives contained in my **www/CI/.htaccess** file were just useless as I emptied it and it continued working like before.

From that point on, I realised that the only thing I needed was to permanently redirect my **www/CI** directory (pointing to CI.example.com) to the 'default_controller' URL of my CodeIgniter instance which, in my case, was '**start**'.

So, my final **www/CI/.htaccess** file ended up like this:

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /start
```

And it all works fine now :)

Thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /CI/index.php?/$1 [L] instead of RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

Comment: Thanks for your reply... but it did not work. Any more ideas?